# Kivy not showing an image

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a simple app that will present an image after a button is clicked.

So far I have managed to create the button in the `ShootButton` class and bind it to the `Bullet` class. The problem is that after the 'Bullet' class is being called, the image does not appear. I know that the class is called because it does prints "test", but no image.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


Window.size = (360, 640)

class Game(Widget):
    pass


class ShootButton(Widget):
    def shoot(self):
        shooting = Bullet()
        shooting.bullet_fly()

class Bullet(Widget):
    def bullet_fly(self):
        img = Image(source='bullet.png')
        self.add_widget(img)
        print('test')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And the Kv file:

```
<Game>
    ShootButton:


<ShootButton>
    Button:
        text: "shoot!"
        size: 70,50
        font_size: 20
        pos: 100,100
        on_press: root.shoot()
```

Comment: your bullet widget is not defined in the .kv file, I think you should first add the bullet widget to (for example) the ShootButton(Widget) and from there you can 'add_widget'. Because you are calling the Bullet class which does not exist in the .kv file, asking the not existing bullet class to add a widget. So I think there's your problem in this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the *bullet image* to the root (*Game*), use *App.get_running_app().root.add_widget(img)*.

## Snippets

```
class Bullet(Widget):
    def bullet_fly(self):
        img = Image(source='bullet.png', size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40), pos=(85, 200))
        App.get_running_app().root.add_widget(img)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.metrics import dp


Window.size = (360, 640)


class Game(Widget):
    pass


class ShootButton(Widget):
    def shoot(self):
        shooting = Bullet()
        shooting.bullet_fly()


class Bullet(Widget):
    def bullet_fly(self):
        img = Image(source='bullet.jpeg', size_hint_y=None, height=dp(40), pos=(85, 200))
        App.get_running_app().root.add_widget(img)
        print('test')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Bullet flying]

Comment: That did the trick! Just had to change the method that is called on_press in the kv file to `root.shoot()`

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding the bullet widget to the kivy hierarchy.

I believe you would want to do something like this:

```
class ShootButton(Widget):
    def shoot(self):
        shooting = Bullet()
        self.parent.add_widget(shooting.img)
        shooting.bullet_fly()
```